# Template Interface Implementation Class C++ error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop, interface

I'm having a small issue with template inheritance.

If I create an interface class with a template:

```
template<typename Data>   
class InterfaceClass {
   private:
   public:
      virtual Data* foo() = 0; //some function that returns our template type
}
```

Then I create an implementation of this:

```
template<typename MoData>
class Implementation : public InterfaceClass<MoData> {
   private:
   public:
      MoData* foo() { MoData* ptr = NULL; return ptr; } //some implementation
}
```

I seem to have trouble with this working in my compiler. Is this not legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typedef Data>
```

is not correct.

You should use

```
template<class Data>
```

or

```
template<typename Data>
```

Comment: yeah, whoops I have it is typename in my code... not typedef.... my bad... long day lol

Comment: @LeeJacobs If you add the missing `;` it compiles fine with me : http://ideone.com/8PeBDB.

Comment: @LeeJacobs Sorry I was playing with it, try again :)

Comment: ok I tested it out on my system I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typedef Data>
```

is wrong, use

```
template <typename Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add semicolon at the end of class declaration.

```
template<typename Data>   
class InterfaceClass {
   private:
   public:
      virtual Data* foo() = 0; //some function that returns our template type
};
```